# Multiple argparser commands each with mutually exclusive groups

Tags: python

I would like to be able to parse multiple arguments which each are a mutually exclusive group.

I have tried:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

# week
week_parser = subparsers.add_parser('week', help = 'input type for week')
week_group = week_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = True)
week_group.add_argument('--list', '-l', help = '"1 2 3 4"')
week_group.add_argument('--single', '-s', help = '25')
week_group.add_argument('--range', '-r', help = '1:10')

# year
year_parser = subparsers.add_parser('year', help = 'input type for year')
year_group = year_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = True)
year_group.add_argument('--list', '-l', help = '"2016 2017"')
year_group.add_argument('--single', '-s', help = '2017')
year_group.add_argument('--range', '-r', help = '2015:2017')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

I would like to do something like:

```
python program.py week -s 25 year -l "2016 2017"
```

Thank you.

Comment: I get an `error: argument --list/-l: not allowed with argument --single/-s`. Maybe the problem is the program gets `year -l  "2016 2017"` as an argument for `week -s`

Comment: I get an `error: argument --list/-l: not allowed with argument --single/-s`. Maybe the problem is the program gets `year -l  "2016 2017"` as an argument for `week -s`

Comment: I get an `error: argument --list/-l: not allowed with argument --single/-s`. Maybe the problem is the program gets `year -l  "2016 2017"` as an argument for `week -s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subcommand approach doesn't work because the parser expects to find only one subcommand on a given command line. You can no doubt modify that behaviour, but I suspect it would involve a disproportionate amount of work.

You may have to settle for one of the following alternatives: (1) Disambiguate your argument names:

```
python program.py --week-single 25 --year-list "2016 2017"
```

or (2) Define `--week` and `--year` to accept strings and parse and validate them yourself:

```
python program.py --week 25 --year "2016 2017"
```

Comment: This sounds like a good option. I could then combine it with mutually_exclusive_groups.